# error 0x80070055 when provisioning a site collection with Document Center or Record Center

Tags: site-collection, web-template, provisioning

In QC we are getting 0x80070055 error when provisioning a site collection with web template Document Center or Record Center template.

Did some googleing and learned this error is due to dup guid in content type. But these 2 web templates are built in web template and has not been messed with.

What are my option? Is there a way to replace the web templates in QC with production just for Doc Ctr and Record Ctr web template?

Comment: Sorry if this question seems naive. does QC stands for test environment?

Comment: I meant Test environment. Can anyone shed some lights on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used PowerShell to create the Document Center site collection. However, would love to know why creating through UI still an issue?

```
########   MUST CREATE MANAGED PATH WITH EXPLICIT  #######

## Configure the script
$databaseName = "SP2010_Content_DB"
$webApplicationUrl = "http://portal.company.com"
$siteCollectionUrl = "http://portal.company.com/sales"
#siteCollectionName = "Construction Document Center"
$siteCollectionOwner1 = "domain\username"
$siteCollectionOwner2 = "domain\username2"
$siteCollectionTemplate = "BDR#0"

## Create the content database
New-SPContentDatabase -Name $databaseName -WebApplication $webApplicationUrl    

## Create the site collection
New-SPSite -URL $siteCollectionUrl -OwnerAlias $siteCollectionOwner1 -SecondaryOwnerAlias $siteCollectionOwner2 -ContentDatabase $databaseName -Name $siteCollectionName -Template $siteCollectionTemplate
```